# Mac book pro early 2011 won't boot

Tags: macbook-pro

my mac book pro 2011 started having weird instances where it would just cut off and shut down immediately. Then when I tried powering it on, the indicator light would light up for 1 or 2 seconds before completely cutting off as if it were a power failure.

Sometimes I managed to boot it up again after waitint for awhile and I managed to do an aht test on it, revealing no problems with memory or the logic board.

What could be causing all this?

Edit: sometimes I get about 5 minutes of usage before it shuts down completely again.

Here's a video of how my mac is trying to boot up.  https://youtu.be/wNEMUeyYfxY

Comment: Dead battery? Try something like [Coconut Battery](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) to check its health.

Comment: Is it most likely a battery fault? Cause if it is I might have no choice but to get it repaired straight tomorrow. Its not booting up again.

Comment: Hard to tell really - that would remove most doubt, though

Comment: Just uploaded a video of how the mac responds to a power up with and without being plugged in. Fans start for a moment before power completely cuts out.

Comment: Does it come on under outlet power?  Is it only battery power where it shuts down?  I can't see the video from my location <cough, work, cough>...

Comment: I've tried powering on both with and without outlet source and also with outlet source but without battery plugged in. All returned the same results.

Comment: I think it's Apple Store time

Comment: ^^   Maybe you can wait a few weeks for the new MBP's?  Of course, if you buy now you might get a deal on a new MBP that, parts-wise, is only a little newer than what you get now.

Comment: I've got some coverage for a new mac for my university enrollment  but only after August next year :( right now I'm pretty much stuck on this MacBook pro.

Comment: Did you try booting from your diagnostic DVD?

Comment: Tried booting to super drive. Didn't work too.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the [NVRAM](http://apple.co/1pMcHzP) and the [SMC](http://apple.co/1ENyxqS)?  Also, the next time you are able to boot open up a Terminal session and execute the following command:  `syslog | grep -i "shutdown cause"` and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

The repairman said that it's a logic board failure. I sent it for repair and am currently waiting for news on what could be the cause. Anyway its gonna cost $350 sgd for the repairs.

Comment: did he say what exactly caused it or just that its a fault of some kind? most good shops should give you a description of what happened and why.

Comment: He hasn't done a full diagnostics yet. I guess he'll have to test every component with a multimeter and pair it up with the schematics etc.

Comment: thats part of it, thou shall check voltages. then its checking if the SMC is on, if it is, he will then check if the circuitry generating the required power on signal is working, I could go on for a very long time but I will save that for somewhere more required.

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah probably gotta go through some extensive testing. I'll update you guys when I find out what's wrong. I hope the processor and other sensitive components are fully functional, I did an aht scan previously and during the phase where it keeps shutting down but the logic board tested fine. I hope it's just the power distribution circuit or something.

Answer (score 0):

2011-2013 MacBook Pros have a problem with their graphic card!

The GPU is overheating and overheats the motherboard. As a result the leads get faulty resulting in unstable systems.

I went trough this.

There used to be a replacement programme.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: But my graphics card never had any distortion problems. Plus I'm using Intel graphics card.

Comment: This problem only happens with dedicated GPUs. In case your MBP does not have one than this does not apply. So maybe an exhausted battery as the other commenter suggested.

Comment: In my case computer stopped working and turned off. Usually the screen would freeze, sometimes with strange artifacts on it.

Comment: Ah that's definitely the GPU. I read it up online too. I'm gonna have it checked by a Mac repair shop later. I really hope it's the battery at fault and not the logic board.

Comment: I am certain that the GPU is part of the CPU..

Comment: @OzzieSpin Basic MacBook Pro models have only integrated Intel GPU, but the better models have both integrated and dedicated GPU. A specific chip switches between integrated and dedicated. Ler Ws' problem could be related to motherboard or battery. The problem with highly integrated systems is heat dissipation. MacBook Pros' can get really hot and this can cause problems with or without dedicated GPU. Motherboard would be quite expensive (around 700 € new and less if reconditioned). Battery would be far cheaper! Watch out reconditioned Motherboards usually have only had a reflow made!!

Comment: ah, a dead graphics mux would suck.. or just go to apple, and get a new motherboard.

Comment: The problem with the motherboard is if it is new or reconditioned, even at Apple! There are a lot of articles about MBP motherboard repair services with different quality levels. You should ask what kind of motherboard and what kind of guaranty they give you. Good Luck!

Comment: @SEJU thanks. I'll keep that in mind. Wow I'm quite surprised it costs that much for a reflow. But it's good to know that heat could be a contributing factor. Perhaps I shouldn't stress my mac out too much. I use xcode quite abit and I run many tabs on google chrome. My fans are always blasting away at full speed.

Comment: These machines are Pro machines, no need to be afraid about stressing them! Your scenario is actually light to medium. The problem is when we upgrade always to the ultimate OS-X! Nevertheless sufficient ventilation is critical for a MBP!